# Who owns the intellectual property of Thinking Machines today?

Tags: history

Who owns the intellectual property regarding the Connection Machine and other products from Thinking Machines? I believe the remnants were bought by Sun, so possibly Oracle, but does anyone know?

Comment: While the retrowizards ponder your question, here's some fun reading material about the hiring process at Thinking Machines: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Thinking-Machines

Comment: Once done reading the article that @traal pointed at, also make sure to check out at least the featured comments.

Comment: The [US Trademark database](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov) seems to indicate the trademarks are all abandoned. If that's right, then no one owns them at the moment, and you could pick them up yourself if you like.

Comment: I'm not familiar but they sound like likely victims of the last generation's "AI Bubble".

Comment: Any patents they might have at the time of their bankruptcy in 1994 would have since expired. If the trademarks have also expired, like Michael Kohne said, then the only intellectual property left would be the copyrights on the software they created.

Comment: @MichaelKohne The copyright on their code, documentation and design schematics would probably be of more value and they won't have expired yet.

Comment: @JeremyP - I actually don't think any of that would be of any commercial value today. Schematics and hardware design used technology that's now 20 years obsolete. And the code is written for a very specific set of hardware, making it interesting only as a historical artifact.

Comment: I hope whoever owns the copyright to code and schematics would consider open sourcing them. I want an FPGA implementation of a slice on my desk. :)

Comment: I worked at TMC at the time it declared bankruptcy. IIRC, Sun Microsystems acquired most of the assets and employees that were not retained by the restructured company (which went from being a hardware manufacturer to data mining software). Sun was later acquired by Oracle, so I suspect they own the patents.

Comment: @Barmar I began looking into the patents - they were all over the place but have long since expired now. There's not much point looking into them now.

Comment: There is no such thing as [intellectual property](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/not-ipr.en.html)